# In the for loop why does it not square the last number in the list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a code that will add up a list of numbers which have been squared. I am pretty new to python, so I was wondering if someone could explain why the `list1` produced does not include the last number squared. The `list2` always seems to start with `0`. Can someone explain why?

```
import math
list2=[]
values=input("Please enter your vector coordinates")
list1=values.split()
print(list1)


for i in range(len(list1)):
    value=i**2
    list2.append(value)

print(list2)
```

Comment: You are squaring indices, not the value at those indices and I'm sure you passed list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is the index, not the value, you can use either indexing:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    value = list1[i]**2
    list2.append(value)
```

Or simply use `for i in list1`:

```
for i in list1:
    value = i**2
    list2.append(value)
```

Even simpler with a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [i ** 2 for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list2` always starts with a `0` because the first value of `i` is always `0`. When you call `range(len(list1))`, you are asking for all the numbers in the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N; where N is the number of elements in `list1`. Note that these are not the specific elements in `list1`.

Assuming that `list1` has numbers in it, creating `list2` with the squares of the corresponding numbers can be achieved in this way:

```
list2 = []
for num in list1:
    v = num**2
    list2.append(v)
```

There's another error in your code: `list1` does not contain numbers as desired. In fact, it contains a bunch of strings (each of which looks like a number) but these are `str`s, not `int`s. This is because `input` returns a string, not ints. Continuing from there, `values.split()` gives you a list of strings, not a list of numbers. So you'll have to cast them to `int`s yourself:

```
list1 = [int(v) for v in values.split()]
```

Here's how I'd write this code:

```
list2 = []
values = input("Please enter your vector coordinates")
list1 = list(map(int, values.split()))
print(list1)

for num in list1:
    list2.append(num**2)

print(list2)
```